# What is the Arduino equivalent of C#'s Mathf.pingpong?

Tags: math, arduino

In C#, more specifically in Unity, there is a a method called [Mathf.PingPong](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html). What is the equivalent for Arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Unity, but if I understand the definition of that function correctly, you can use the modulo operator.

```
int pingpong(int t, int length)
{
    return t % length;
}
```

You can probably use fmod, if you need floating point numbers.

Edit: I assume you mean in C when you are talking about arduino.

Comment: Thanks @Kake_Fisk, I'm not at home at the moment but I will try that when I get home, and yes by Arduino I am referring to C